# How to preserve dynamically created controls?

Tags: asp.net

I want to preserve the dynamically created control when postback occurs .

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void CreateTable()
{
    HtmlTableRow objHtmlTblRow = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell objHtmlTableCell = new HtmlTableCell();
    objHtmlTableCell.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
    objHtmlTblRow.Cells.Add(objHtmlTableCell);
    mytable.Rows.Add(objHtmlTblRow);
    this.SaveControlState();
  //  this.Controls.Add(mytable);
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateTable();
}
```

> It can be achieved by calling CreateTable() in Page_Load. Is there any alternative way to preserve the control

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add them to a List when you create them and save your List to Session. On postback (Page_Load) load them from your Session to your Page.

Answer (score 0):

the below code should work

```
  protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control myControl = GetPostBackControl(this.Page);
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    CreateTable()

}


public static Control GetPostBackControl(Page thisPage)
{

    Control ctrlPostedback = null;
    string ctrlName = thisPage.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrlName))
    {
        ctrlPostedback = thisPage.FindControl(ctrlName);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (string Item in thisPage.Request.Form)
        {
            Control c = thisPage.FindControl(Item);
            if (((c) is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button))
            {
                ctrlPostedback = c;
            }
        }

    }
    return ctrlPostedback;
}
```

The code works from UpdatePanel
Reference:http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-to-dynamically-add-controls-to-a-web-page